# OpenCV, Change to nearest color in image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I currently have the following code, it searches for a range of colors (blue) and is replacing it with a specific color, however, I would like to replace it with the closest color in the image, not the closest in the palette but in the image.

How can I do this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('test5.jpeg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue = np.array([80,50,50], dtype="uint8")
upper_blue = np.array([101,255,255], dtype="uint8")

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

#image[mask > 0] = (183, 213, 247)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate or add a picture to explain the question better.? When you say closest color in the image, do you mean a colour that is lower than lower_blue or upper than upper_blue? Or do you mean to say that the color should be of the adjacent pixels in the image?

Comment: I'll try to add a public image with this case, but I mean adjacent pixels in the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

mask = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
gray_mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image = cv2.inpaint(image, gray_mask, 100, flags=cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

I could solve my problem using the `inpaint` method.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/18/image-inpainting-with-opencv-and-python/